# Select result of two Hive tables as JSON output

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

I have a requirement where I need to join multiple Hive tables which are in ORC format and present the output as JSON.

For example if I have two Hive tables with 1 to many relationship, I want the output to be JSON with embedded relationship and array.

Is there native Hive UDF we can use to achieve this ?

I tried googling stuff like to_JSON from https://github.com/klout/brickhouse but looking for something more Hadoop native and not third party.

Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create **`Hive table`** using [JsonSerDe](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RowFormats&SerDe).

Then insert into json table by selecting the result of join.

***Example:***

```
Insert into json_table 
select t1.* from tab1 t1 join tab2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id;
```

The files in Hive table's(hdfs directory) will be in **Json format**.